# Selenium RC popup window question

Tags: popup, postback, selenium-rc

My webpage submits information to a page and the response returns a popup window. Does anyone have an idea about how I can validate the information in the popup window?

Popup window doesn't have a `WindowId` and I'm not able to get hold of the popup window using `selenium.GetWindow("popuwindowname")`, `selenium.GetWindow("title=something")` or `selenium.GetWindow("name=popupwindowname")`.

Has anyone had a similar problem and found a workaround or an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the html source of the popup window. Usually, what you see in the screen may different in the html code.

Answer (score 0):

What type of popup dialog is returned if this is a modal dialog selenium does not handle modal dialogs.because a modal dialog stops all javascripts from running until it is closed.
see [Selenium FAQ](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium%2BCore%2BFAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-Ican%27tinteractwithapopupdialog.Myteststopsinitstracks!)

Comment: That's not 100% true.  Selenium can't deal with popups as the page loads, but after that, it swaps out common popup functions (such as alert()) with its own implementation that captures the text and does not show the popup.  This prevents the application from hanging and allows you to verify the popup text in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void testPopup() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("http://yoursitename/page.aspx");
    selenium.click("//img[@alt='Share']");
    selenium.waitForPopUp("_blank", "30000");
    selenium.selectPopUp("");
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Recommend to a friend"));
    selenium.close();
```

Hope will help you!

Comment: Can you plz tell how to get the window id